# Existence of element of degree p in $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_{p^n})$ over $\mathbf{Q}$

Tags: field-theory

Let $\zeta = \exp\left(2\pi i/p^n\right)$, where $p$ is a prime number, and $n$ is at least 2. Does there exist an element in $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta)$ which is of degree $p$ over $\mathbf{Q}$?

I imagine one would make use of the tower law for field extensions, as well as the fact that the degree of $\zeta$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ is $p^{n-1}(p-1)$, and exploiting symmetries (i.e. identities that $\zeta$ satisfy) but any suggestions beyond that would be greatly appreciated.