# Element of degree 5 in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{25})$

Tags: field-theory

I want to find an element of degree 5 over $\mathbb{Q}$, in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{25})$. I searched, but only found elements of degree 1, 4, 10, and 20. Is there such an element or no?

Here $\zeta_{25} = e^{2\pi i/25}$.

Comment: A good approach to these problems is to look at the Galois group, have you seen that yet?

Comment: No. I saw this but don't understand. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242662/existence-of-element-of-degree-p-in-mathbfq-zeta-pn-over-mathbfq?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Galois group is multiplicative group of integers mod 25 which has $\phi(25)=25-5=20$ elements. This group is cyclic. A generator for this group is $2$ (that is, powers of 2 modulo 25 provide all numbers less than 25 coprime to 25).

This means the automorphism  $\sigma$ of the cyclotomic field that generates the Galois group is the map given by $\zeta\mapsto \zeta^2$. (here $\zeta $denotes a primitive 25th root of unity)

To get a subfield of degree 5, take the subgroup generated by$\sigma^5$ and apply those automorphisms to $\zeta$ and sum them.

Now $\sigma^5:\zeta\mapsto\zeta^{2^5}=\zeta^{32}=\zeta^7$.

For the group generated by this element we get $\zeta^7,\zeta^{49}=\zeta^{24},\zeta^{24\times7}=\zeta^{18}, \zeta^{18\times7}=\zeta^{126}=\zeta$.

Summing these four elements: $\zeta^7+\zeta^{24}+\zeta^{18}+\zeta$ is an element of degree $5$.

EDIT: In response to user1952009's comment below I indicate how to show this number is not rational.

Suffices to show, e.g., it is not fixed by the the automorphism $\sigma^3:\zeta\mapsto \zeta^8$. Assume otherwise leading to an equality:
$$\zeta +\zeta^7+\zeta^{18}+\zeta^{24}=\zeta^8+\zeta^{6}+\zeta^{19}+\zeta^{17}  $$
As the $\zeta$ has degree 20, to keep all powers within  $20$ in the above equation, let us multiply by $\zeta$ which gives us
$$\zeta^2+\zeta^8+\zeta^{19}+1=\zeta^9+\zeta^7+\zeta^{20}+\zeta^{18}$$
Rearrange the above to get a polynomial expression of degree $<20$ giving $g(\zeta)=0$. This contradicts the fact that $\zeta$ has   minimal polynomial $X^{20}+x^{15}+X^{10}+X^5+1=0$

Comment: That's my answer there : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2242703/276986 but I'm not sure how to show $\sum_{r=1}^{\phi(p)/p} \zeta^{g^{rp}}$ is not rational in general